# vue props gets displayed as undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is my parent component.

```
<FolderList
          :showData="false"
          :propClientObj="{clientno: clientno, clientname:`${clientObj.fname} ${clientObj.lname} ${clientObj.cname}`}"
        />
```

This are the child components

1) FolderList

```
<FolderCreateM
              :folderno="folder.folderno"
              :propClientObj="propClientObj"
              @foldersave="getFolder"
            />
```

and

2)FolderCreateM

```
<template>
<v-row>
<v-col md="8" class="py-0">
            <v-autocomplete
              v-model="clientno"
              :items="clientListArr"
              label="Select Client"
              item-text="clientname"
              item-value="clientno"
              dense
            ></v-autocomplete>
          </v-col>
          <v-col md="4" class="py-0">
            <v-text-field outlined readonly dense label="Client No" v-model="clientno"></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
</v-row>
</template>

export default {
name: "FolderCreateM",
  props: {
    folderno: {
      type: String,
      default() {
        return null;
      }
    },
    propClientObj: {
      type: Object,
      default() {
        return null;
      }
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      clientListArr: [],
      clientno:""
    }
  }
  mounted() {
    this.clientListArr = [this.propClientObj];
    this.clientno = lo_get(this.propClientObj, "clientno", "");

    this.getClientList();
  }
}
```

Now inside my clientlistArr in 2nd component the clientname is printed as `undefined undefined undefined`. But the client no does gets printed in the text field. How do I resolve the following issue.

Comment: try to `console.log(this.propClientObj)`  and check if the client name is in there

Comment: try to change your mounted hook into created hook

Comment: Also it is advised to use kebab case when defining props in html like this `<folder-list :prop-client-obj="">`

Comment: @ChristhoferNatalius [Not quite](https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Self-closing-components-strongly-recommended).

Comment: If you're seeing `undefined undefined undefined` it sounds like there's a problem with your parent component trying to access `clientObj.fname`, etc.. You'd need to include the code for populating `clientObj` for us to help resolve that.

Comment: Yes you're right, the child component was called before the parent data was ready. The issue is solved now. Thanks for your help.